# REST payload max size?

Tags: rest

We are thinking of using a REST interface for communication between internal apps.  App A will have to pass a fair bit of data representing a financial portfolio to app B.  Is there any limit to the amount of data that can be passed using a REST API given that REST is implemented using HTTP?  I wasn't sure if another protocol (ie: RMI) should be used with a large data set.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No, it's pretty much up to the server implementation if there's any such limit.

There's a limit on the size of a URL (if you wish to put large amounts of data on the URL, like with a GET), but no defined limit for a POST or PUT.

Comment: That's true, but I'd like to add that, for large posts and over significant latencies, performance may become an issue, if only because of TCP/IP's limitations.  The typical work-around is to upload multiple parts in parallel.

Answer (score 59):

As Will Hartung said, there is no limit in the standard ([RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)). But every implementation has its own limits. A few examples:

- Two megabytes for Tomcat (you can change it with  [maxPostSize](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html))
- Two megabytes for PHP (you can change it with [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size))
- Two megabytes for Apache itself (you can change it with [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody))

These implementation limits are usually just the default configuration values, and can be changed to larger ones if required.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, at least for Tomcat. maxPostSize only affects payloads with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I suspect the PHP answer has the same limitation, though Apache's LimitRequestBody does seem to do what is being requested.

Comment: And what is the limit on GET response size? Same as for POST?

Comment: From PHP documentation: `Allow unlimited post size by setting post_max_size to 0.`