# WCF service streaming - Console host vs. IIS host

Tags: wcf, iis, streaming

I've created a streamed wcf service based on that example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112655/Progress-Streamed-File-download-and-Upload-with-Re

With console host works everything fine, the upload and the writing run "parallel". But if I host the service in IIS, it seems, that the stream is buffered on the server side.

1. Why? What is the difference? Is the service with console host not reliable?! (I need reliable streming!)
2. How can I avoid that with IIS host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it: [Getting Streaming in IIS Hosted WCF service to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225229/getting-streaming-in-iis-hosted-wcf-service-to-work)

> I think this is a known issue (streaming with .net 4.0 and iis 7).
>   When a WCF service using streaming is hosted in IIS then ASP.net
>   buffers the request at its layer. The request does not even come up to
>   WCF until ASP.Net is done with it.
>
> This should work when using non-HTTP transport IIS or hosting in a
>   non-IIS host.
>
> (Zulfiqar Ahmed)
>
> on contacting the product team - they said it would be fixed in .NET
>   4.5 as its too big to be issued as a patch.

And it works with .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

How do you know its buffered? Check the config file on the client side after proxy generation. Sometimes the proxy generated config file has incorrect transfermode.

When you start writing the file on the client, don't any see any chunk wise increase in the size of file?

The hosting shouldn't affect the transfermode.

The only difference between IIS and Console would be the way activation/deactivation is managed.

Comment: I checked it with Fiddler, the call comes, but my function will be called just later. I use the same web.config/app.config in the self hosted and in the iis hosted scenario (Streamed, Mtom).