# GAS - What's the max size of the payload I can send through the Execution API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a relatively big Google Docs file using Google Apps Script, and I basically need to inject a lot of data in order to build it programatically.

I'm thinking of executing a function `init()` and passing the json string as it value through the Execution API. I'm worried about the max size of the string that I can pass. What's the max size?

Answer (score 0):

Checked the documentation for  the docs on [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api) but there is no mention of such limit. If it follows the standard protocol [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495541/rest-payload-max-size), then your big payload may push through. The only thing you need to do now is actually try.