# Maximum size of payload for an AWS Lambda Request / Event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, amazon-gateway

What is the max payload for a REST post request to AWS lamda?

[This question is essentially this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495541/rest-payload-max-size), but for AWS Lambda HTTP events.

Also does AWS Gateway add any restriction of payload size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda has a strict payload limit size of 6MB.
If you want to upload more than 6MB you can do like this,

> Lambda (Create S3 Signed URL) --> Upload to S3 --> Trigger from S3 to
>   lambda --> Process in lambda

**Lambda Limits:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

**API Gateway Limits:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Hope it helps.