# Set maximum payload size to POST request in django rest framework api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for mobile application. now I want to set the maximum data limit that client side can sent to POST api. How can i set that limit in DRF (django rest framework)?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495554/8091237) but i need in more details.

Update:

also referred [this](http://DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE%20=%203*1024*1024) . Added `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 3*1024*1024` in settings.py file and hit POST api with 5.6MB payload data, still its accepting that data.

Comment: There is a Django setting for limiting request size `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size

Answer (score 2):

In setting.py add

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE=10*1024*1024
```

Default size is 2621440 (i.e. 2.5 MB) // 2.5*1024*1024

Also refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size

Comment: I tried using this but it is not giving any error. I used this in settings.py file "DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 3*1024*1024". and wrote request.data in function still its accepting it

Answer (score 0):

According to comments in [this issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4760) on DRF's Github, the `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` setting suggested in other answers is not respected by DRF because of the way DRF reads the requests, so it seems that there is no obvious easy solution for this.

One possible solution of integrating checks for this setting into DRF's parsers is presented in a comment in the linked github issue. I suppose you could write custom parsers that implement the necessary checking (for more info on writing and using custom parsers see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/).