# What's the body request size limit for a PUT request?

Tags: spring-boot, http, tomcat, put

I've created a PUT endpoint on a tomcat server using Spring boot. For safety reasons, I don't want the body size to exceed a certain amount, so I was checking whether there is a limit as there is for POST requests ([which I know stays at 2MB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size))

At the same time I don't find any documentation for the PUT requests. Is there a limit for those too?

Comment: Curious if you tried to use PUT for over 2 MB and if it allowed you or not.  It might consider a PUT request, the same as a POST request since it is sending data, so the 2 MB limit might also apply.  You will know once you try it.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495541/rest-payload-max-size ?